# How to use slug in root URL

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.1

I am working on a CMS of my own, but I'm experiencing some difficulties with slugs, so, here is my problem:

I'm trying to use slugs on the root of my URLs like so:

http://domain.com/some-slug-to-some-article

At this point I have the following entries in my app/routes.php

```
Route::get('/', 'ArticleController@index');
Route::get('/{slug?}', 'ArticleController@show');
```

The problem appears when I am try to enter to the "login" area of the site, which for default is in /home (I'm using the scaffold for user authentication in Laravel 5.1)

When I enter the URL for domain.com/home it stills calling it as a slug.

Here's my route:list

```
+--------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method                         | URI                                                   | Name                 | Action                                                     | Middleware |
+--------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD                       | /                                                     |                      | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@index               |            |
|        | POST                           | auth/login                                            |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@postLogin         | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | auth/login                                            |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getLogin          | guest      |
|        | POST                           | auth/login/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}     |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@postLogin         | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | auth/login/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}     |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getLogin          | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | auth/logout                                           |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getLogout         |            |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | auth/logout/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}    |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getLogout         |            |
|        | POST                           | auth/register                                         |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@postRegister      | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | auth/register                                         |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getRegister       | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | auth/register/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}  |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getRegister       | guest      |
|        | POST                           | auth/register/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}  |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@postRegister      | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | auth/{_missing}                                       |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@missingMethod     | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | home                                                  |                      | \Bestmomo\Scafold\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index    | auth       |
|        | POST                           | home/article                                          | home.article.store   | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@store               | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | home/article                                          | home.article.index   | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@index               | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | home/article/create                                   | home.article.create  | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@create              | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | home/article/{article}                                | home.article.show    | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@show                | auth       |
|        | PUT                            | home/article/{article}                                | home.article.update  | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@update              | auth       |
|        | DELETE                         | home/article/{article}                                | home.article.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@destroy             | auth       |
|        | PATCH                          | home/article/{article}                                |                      | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@update              | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | home/article/{article}/edit                           | home.article.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@edit                | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | password/email/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@getEmail      | guest      |
|        | POST                           | password/email/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@postEmail     | guest      |
|        | POST                           | password/reset/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@postReset     | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | password/reset/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@getReset      | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | password/{_missing}                                   |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@missingMethod | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | {slug?}                                               |                      | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@show                |            |
+--------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-------------
```

So in short words, I want to have the slugs at the root of the URL but also, I want to "exclude" some routes to keep it to the system itself.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try making the `slug` parameter mandatory, i.e. `{slug}`.

Comment: Hmm I have had the same case using Laravel 4, but I had it fixed by defining my slug routes **after** all my other routes. You can try to do the opposite, but I doubt they have changed the logic that much. A better suggestion would be to try removing the question mark from the slug route and thus making it mandatory

Comment: @StuartWagner I've tried that also. Didn't work.

Comment: @Avalanche The problem is that the route for "home" comes implicit within the framework, is not even declared in routes.php so I cannot move it.

Comment: @AndreX `/home` isn't normally added by Laravel. It must be defined somewhere. If you clear out your `routes.php` file completely, `artisan route:list` should not return any routes.

Comment: @StuartWagner I've solved it creating a specific route for home:

Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

Answer (score 0):

For further requirements, I've solved the problem adding this rule at the beginning of the routes.php

```
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Also, @StuartWagner said that clearing the routes.php should be empty the routes this was not true at all, once cleared the routes.php this is what the `php artisan route:list` show me:

```
+--------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method                         | URI                                                   | Name | Action                                                     | Middleware |
+--------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | POST                           | auth/login/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}     |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@postLogin         | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | auth/login/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}     |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getLogin          | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | auth/logout/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}    |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getLogout         |            |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | auth/register/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}  |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getRegister       | guest      |
|        | POST                           | auth/register/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}  |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@postRegister      | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | auth/{_missing}                                       |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@missingMethod     | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | home                                                  |      | \Bestmomo\Scafold\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index    | auth       |
|        | POST                           | password/email/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@postEmail     | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | password/email/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@getEmail      | guest      |
|        | POST                           | password/reset/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@postReset     | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | password/reset/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@getReset      | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | password/{_missing}                                   |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@missingMethod | guest      |
+--------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

In some where is declared this route for "home".

Hope this helps anyone.

Cheers.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like you have something other than your `routes.php` file defining routes for your application. Are you using any third-party packages for authentication?

Comment: Since Laravel 5.1 doesn't come with the auth preconfigured after installation I've start to use a package that implements the auth system which was in L5, this package creates a routes.php file within the package folder in vendor, and this was "supplanting" the default routes.php